# Displaying if...else result in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Could anyone help me figure out a better way of returning the right message based on my if...else logic? So I'm trying to calculate a student's GPA via dropdown menus. Each letter is your standard fare (A = 4.0, B = 3.5, etc). Now, if a student has a calculated GPA that is >= 3.5, I want to display a certain message. If It's anything lower, I'd display another message. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to print the message based on the condition.

```
    function letterToGrade(gpa){
var grade;
switch (gpa) 
    {
    case "A": grade = 4.0;
        break;
    case "B": grade = 3.0;
        break;
    case "C": grade = 2.0;
        break;
    case "D": grade = 1.0;
        break;
    case "F": grade = 0.0;
        break;
    }
    return grade;
}

function calculateGPA(){

var numOfRequisites = 5;
var gpa1 = letterToGrade(document.getElementById("Foundation").value);
var gpa2 = letterToGrade(document.getElementById("Database").value);
var gpa3 = letterToGrade(document.getElementById("Elect").value);
var gpa4 = letterToGrade(document.getElementById("Commerce").value);
var gpa5 = letterToGrade(document.getElementById("HealthInfo").value);
var gpaTotal = (gpa1 + gpa2 + gpa3 + gpa4 + gpa5)/numOfRequisites ;
var result = "<p>Your calculated GPA is: "+(gpaTotal.toFixed(1))+"<br></p>";
if (gpaTotal >= 3.5)
    return result += "<p>Congratulations! Based on your GPA, we will move forward with your application " + 
"for this prestigious internship program.</p>";
else 
    return result += "<p>Thank you for your interest in this program. Unfortunately at this time, " +
"we are unable to continue with your application due to our strict GPA standards. Please try again " + 
"at a later time.</p>";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=result;
}
```

And here's the HTML. Not all of it.

```
<h4>Thank you for your interest in our summer internship program. Please enter your GPA for the following courses. </h4>
<p>
IT 3503 Foundation of HIT:
<select id="Foundation">
<option> </option>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>F</option>
</select>
    <br/>
IT 4153 Advanced Database:
<select id="Database">
<option> </option>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>F</option>
</select>
    <br/>
IT 4513 Elect Health Rec Sys & Ap:
<select id="Elect">
<option> </option>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>F</option>
</select>
    <br/>
IT 4123 Electronic Commerce:
<select id="Commerce">
<option> </option>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>F</option>
</select>
    <br/>
IT 4533 Health Info Sec & Priv:
<select id="HealthInfo">
<option> </option>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>F</option>
</select>
    <br/>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="calculateGPA()" />

</p>
```

The last part kind of messes me up. I'm pretty new to HTML and Javascript. This is for a school assignment, so please feel free to insult me as you will for being a slacker.

Comment: What is supposed to happen and what do you see happening instead?

Comment: Use a local variable to store the grade or multiple functions. Right now `calculategpa` returns the grade only. The rest of the function will not run as a result. But then again Where is the function getting the grade?

Comment: On the actual HTML page, nothing is happening, and with the way my Jscript is now, I don't expect anything to happen. There's no way the browser can tell which message I want to display.

Comment: you have `switch(grade)` but i do not see grade being defined anywhere, and you return right after the switch so the rest is not executed.

Comment: Where is your HTML page and define "better way".

Comment: `"On the actual HTML page, nothing is happening, and with the way my Jscript is now, I don't expect anything to happen."` Then what do you want to happen? I guess I am a little confused. Can you formulate your issue into a specific question?

Comment: post your function header, or full code so we can understand what's going on

Comment: @HanH1113 Your function does way too many things and that's why you're having trouble debugging it. Try refactoring your code where every function has a single responsability. Also, do not mix any business logic code with presentation logic or code interacting with the DOM. E.g. `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = messageForGpaTotal(calcGpaTotal());`

Comment: @plalx I edited my code a little bit. Split the functions up. One takes a letter grade and switches to a number accordingly. Then I have the calculate GPA function. I can't get the results to display.

Answer (score 2):

you have several problems

1. `grade` is never defined
2. you return before the other code can be executed
3. numGrade is undefined. probably mean for CalculateGPA to be numGrade, or vise versa

So

```
function CalculateGPA(){
    //grade here is undefined as it isnt declared before here
    switch (grade) {
        case "A": 
            grade = 4.0;
        break;
        case "B": 
            grade = 3.0;
            break;
        case "C": 
            grade = 2.0;
        break;
        case "D": 
            grade = 1.0;
        break;
        case "F": 
            grade = 0.0;
            break;
        }
        return grade; //you return here so any code after this is never executed
    var numOfRequisites = 5;
    var gpa1 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Foundation").value);
    var gpa2 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Database").value);
    var gpa3 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Elect").value);
    var gpa4 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Commerce").value);
    var gpa5 = numGrade(document.getElementById("HealthInfo").value);
    var gpaTotal = (gpa1 + gpa2 + gpa3 + gpa4 + gpa5)/numOfRequisites ;
    if (gpaTotal >= 3.5)
        return acceptanceMessage;
    else 
        return consolationMessage;
    //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=message;
}
```

i think you want:

```
function numGrade(gpa){
   switch (gpa) {
      case "A": gpa = 4.0;
      break;
      case "B": gpa = 3.0;
      break;
      case "C": gpa = 2.0;
      break;
      case "D": gpa = 1.0;
      break;
      case "F": gpa = 0.0;
      break;
    }
    return gpa;
}

function calculateGradeAndGenMessage(){
    var numOfRequisites = 5;
    var gpa1 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Foundation").value);
    var gpa2 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Database").value);
    var gpa3 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Elect").value);
    var gpa4 = numGrade(document.getElementById("Commerce").value);
    var gpa5 = numGrade(document.getElementById("HealthInfo").value);
    var gpaTotal = (gpa1 + gpa2 + gpa3 + gpa4 + gpa5)/numOfRequisites ;
    if (gpaTotal >= 3.5)
        return acceptanceMessage;
    else 
        return consolationMessage;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=calculateGradeAndGenMessage();
```

Comment: Whenever there's an *and* in your function names, there's something wrong with your design ;)

Comment: @plalx Thanks! Tips like these are very useful for a newbie like me. So functions should do one thing at most huh?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you never defined `gpa`.  However, I noticed you wanted to clean up your code a bit...I recommend going about this by breaking it up into two functions:

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Q86gt/4/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//Calculate average GPA of 5 classes. 
//If avereage GPA >= 3.5, show acceptance message.
//Else thank for applying. 
var consolationMessage = "<p>Thank you for your interest in this program. Unfortunately at this time, " +
    "we are unable to continue with your application due to our strict GPA standards. Please try again " +
    "at a later time.";

var acceptanceMessage = "Congratulations! Based on your GPA, we will move forward with your application " +
    "for this prestigious internship program."

    //get the gpa
    function getGPA() {
        var gpaTotal = null,
            message = null,
            classes = ['Foundation', 'Database', 'Elect', 'Commerce', 'HealthInfo'];

        //iterate over classes
        for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            var gpa = calculateGPA(document.getElementById(classes[i]).value);
            gpaTotal += gpa;
        }
        //gpaTotal divided by number of classes
        gpaTotal /= classes.length;

        //if not all values are filled out, alert and return
        if (isNaN(gpaTotal)) {
            alert('Please fill out all answers!');
            return;
        }

        if (gpaTotal >= 3.5) message = acceptanceMessage;
        else message = consolationMessage;

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = message;
    }

    function calculateGPA(gpa) {
        switch (gpa) {
            case "A":
                gpa = 4.0;
                break;
            case "B":
                gpa = 3.0;
                break;
            case "C":
                gpa = 2.0;
                break;
            case "D":
                gpa = 1.0;
                break;
            case "F":
                gpa = 0.0;
                break;
        }
        return gpa;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<h4>Thank you for your interest in our summer internship program. Please enter your GPA for the following courses. </h4>

<p>IT 3503 Foundation of HIT:</p>
<select id="Foundation">
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>F</option>
</select>
<p>IT 4153 Advanced Database:</p>
<select id="Database">
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>F</option>
</select>
<p>IT 4513 Elect Health Rec Sys & Ap:</p>
<select id="Elect">
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>F</option>
</select>
<p>IT 4123 Electronic Commerce:</p>
<select id="Commerce">
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>F</option>
</select>
<p>IT 4533 Health Info Sec & Priv:</p>
<select id="HealthInfo">
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>F</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getGPA()" />
<p id="result"></p>
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

I missed this return statement originally but you `return gpa` after your `switch` statement.

This will cause your function to end as it has been [returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) already.

Then after `return gpa` you have two other unnecessary return statements in your `if` block.

You should break up the calculation of the GPA and the message generation separately.

```
function calculateGPA(letterGrade) {
    var gpa;
    switch (letterGrade) {
        case 'A':
            gpa = 4.0;
            break;
        case 'B':
            gpa = 3.0;
            break;
        case 'C':
            gpa = 2.0;
            break;
        case 'D':
            gpa = 1.0;
            break;
        case 'F':
            gpa = 0.0;
            break;
    }

    return gpa;
}

function averageGPA() {
    var gpas = [],
        sum = 0,
        numberGPA;

    gpas.push(calculateGPA(document.getElementById("Foundation").value));
    gpas.push(calculateGPA(document.getElementById("Database").value));
    gpas.push(calculateGPA(document.getElementById("Elect").value));
    gpas.push(calculateGPA(document.getElementById("Commerce").value));
    gpas.push(calculateGPA(document.getElementById("HealthInfo").value));

    for (var i = gpas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += gpas[i]
    };

    return sum / gpas.length;
}

function passMessage(gpa) {
    var result = document.getElementById('result'),
        message;

    if (gpa >= 3.5) {
        message = "Congratulations! Based on your GPA, we will move forward with your application " +
            "for this prestigious internship program.";
    } else if (gpa < 3.5) {
        message = "Thank you for your interest in this program. Unfortunately at this time, " +
            "we are unable to continue with your application due to our strict GPA standards. Please try again " +
            "at a later time";
    }

    result.innerHTML = message;
}

function checkGPAResults() {
    passMessage(averageGPA());   
}
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9P4A/1/)